# Manipulate an array or json reponse and save it as another array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a json response from another code which is in the format given below:

```
[{"Latitude":"17.4283466666667","Longitude":"78.5797422222222", "VehicleNumber":"TS08UA6743"},
{"Latitude":"17.4282822222222","Longitude":"78.5799111111111","VehicleNumber":"TS08UA6743"},
{"Latitude":"17.4284233333333","Longitude":"78.5797333333333","VehicleNumber":"TS08UA6745"}]
```

I want to change it dynamically and save in an array like given below:

```
var coordinates = {

"TS08UA6743": [
[17.4283466666667,78.5797422222222],
[17.4282822222222,78.5799111111111]
],

"TS08UA6745": [
[17.4284233333333,78.5797333333333]
]

};
```

This seems to be simple but I am new to javascript and unable to deal with arrays can anybody help with the logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**Reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
let data = [{"Latitude":"17.4283466666667","Longitude":"78.5797422222222", "VehicleNumber":"TS08UA6743"},{"Latitude":"17.4282822222222","Longitude":"78.5799111111111","VehicleNumber":"TS08UA6743"},{"Latitude":"17.4284233333333","Longitude":"78.5797333333333","VehicleNumber":"TS08UA6745"}]

let op = data.reduce((out,{VehicleNumber:vn,Latitude:lat,Longitude:lon})=>{
  if(out[vn]){ out[vn].push([lat,lon]) }
  else { out[vn] = [[lat,lon]] }
  return out
},{})

console.log(op)
```

If else inside reduce can be replace by this shorthand but i am keeping it as it is for the shake of readability.

```
((out[vn] ? out[vn].push([lat,lon]) : out[vn]=[[lat,lon]]), out)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for this:

```js
const input = [
  {
    "Latitude":"17.4283466666667",
    "Longitude":"78.5797422222222",
    "VehicleNumber":"TS08UA6743"
  },
  {
    "Latitude":"17.4282822222222",
    "Longitude":"78.5799111111111",
    "VehicleNumber":"TS08UA6743"
  },
  {
    "Latitude":"17.4284233333333",
    "Longitude":"78.5797333333333",
    "VehicleNumber":"TS08UA6745"
  }
];

let res = input.reduce((acc, {Latitude, Longitude, VehicleNumber}) =>
{
    acc[VehicleNumber] = acc[VehicleNumber] || [];
    acc[VehicleNumber].push([Latitude, Longitude]);
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.reduce()` to get the desired output:

```js
const data = [{
    "Latitude": "17.4283466666667",
    "Longitude": "78.5797422222222",
    "VehicleNumber": "TS08UA6743"
}, {
    "Latitude": "17.4282822222222",
    "Longitude": "78.5799111111111",
    "VehicleNumber": "TS08UA6744"
},{
    "Latitude": "17.4284233333333",
    "Longitude": "78.5797333333333",
    "VehicleNumber": "TS08UA6745"
}];

const result = data.reduce(
  (r, {VehicleNumber:vn, Latitude:lt, Longitude:lg}) => (r[vn] = [lt, lg], r), {}
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

check if output has vehiclenumber property. if it contains than update that property otherwise add new vehiclenumber property.

```js
let input = [{"Latitude":"17.4283466666667","Longitude":"78.5797422222222", "VehicleNumber":"TS08UA6743"},
{"Latitude":"17.4282822222222","Longitude":"78.5799111111111","VehicleNumber":"TS08UA6743"},
{"Latitude":"17.4284233333333","Longitude":"78.5797333333333","VehicleNumber":"TS08UA6745"}];

let output = {};
input.map(x=>{
  if(output[x.VehicleNumber]){
     output[x.VehicleNumber] = [...output[x.VehicleNumber], [x.Latitude, x.Longitude]]
  }else{
   output[x.VehicleNumber] = [[x.Latitude, x.Longitude]]
  }
})

console.log(output);
```